# React Native - TypeError: Cannot read property 'clean' of undefined

Tags: android, react-native

React Native v 0.62.2.
`npm run android` gives me below error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'clean' of undefined

> ExceptionsManager.js:76 Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

[image: Console output]

***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
    "postinstall": "rn-nodeify --install process,buffer,crypto,stream,assert,events,vm --hack",
    "graphql:codegen": "apollo client:codegen --target typescript"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/art": "^1.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.10.3",
    "@react-native-community/cameraroll": "^1.7.1",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.2.2",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.2.0",
    "@skele/components": "^1.0.0-alpha.40",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.6",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
    "apollo-link-context": "^1.0.20",
    "apollo-link-error": "^1.1.13",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.17",
    "apollo-link-ws": "^1.0.20",
    "apollo-upload-client": "^13.0.0",
    "assert": "^1.5.0",
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "buffer": "^4.9.2",
    "ethereumjs-abi": "^0.6.8",
    "ethereumjs-util": "^6.2.0",
    "ethereumjs-wallet": "^0.6.3",
    "events": "^1.1.1",
    "firebase": "^7.15.1",
    "graphql": "^14.6.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.3",
    "i18n-js": "^3.5.1",
    "invert-color": "^2.0.0",
    "lodash.memoize": "^4.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-apollo": "^3.1.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.1",
    "react-native": "^0.62.2",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.2",
    "react-native-button": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.28.0",
    "react-native-crypto": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-dark-mode": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "^5.5.7",
    "react-native-dialog-input": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.1.5",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.25.3",
    "react-native-image-filter-kit": "^0.7.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-image-progress": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-image-view": "^2.1.9",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-ionicons": "^4.6.5",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-view": "^0.0.14",
    "react-native-localize": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.27.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-randombytes": "^3.5.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-search-box": "^0.0.19",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-video": "^4.4.5",
    "react-native-view-more-text": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.12.2",
    "react-navigation": "^4.1.0",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.4.11",
    "react-navigation-hooks": "^1.1.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.1.0",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.7.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "readable-stream": "^1.0.33",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.16",
    "rn-nodeify": "^10.2.0",
    "stream-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.9.16",
    "uuidv4": "^6.0.7",
    "vm-browserify": "0.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "@types/apollo-upload-client": "^8.1.3",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.24",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.60.25",
    "@types/react-native-push-notification": "^3.0.9",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "16.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.12.0",
    "apollo": "^2.27.4",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.6",
    "metro": "^0.59.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "react-native": {
    "_stream_transform": "readable-stream/transform",
    "_stream_readable": "readable-stream/readable",
    "_stream_writable": "readable-stream/writable",
    "_stream_duplex": "readable-stream/duplex",
    "_stream_passthrough": "readable-stream/passthrough",
    "stream": "stream-browserify",
    "crypto": "react-native-crypto",
    "vm": "vm-browserify"
  },
  "browser": {
    "_stream_transform": "readable-stream/transform",
    "_stream_readable": "readable-stream/readable",
    "_stream_writable": "readable-stream/writable",
    "_stream_duplex": "readable-stream/duplex",
    "_stream_passthrough": "readable-stream/passthrough",
    "stream": "stream-browserify",
    "crypto": "react-native-crypto",
    "vm": "vm-browserify"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@react-native-community/cli-debugger-ui": "4.7.0"
  }
}
```

***android/bundle.gradle***

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        supportVersion = "28.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.1"
        facebookSdkVersion = "4.37.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }

        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

***android/app/bundle.gradle***

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "3g"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.client"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.12"
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst "lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/x86/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so"
    }
    
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:17.0.0"

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }
    
    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: attach your JS file which error occures

Comment: @AkilaDevinda Its in `ExceptionsManger.js`, its generic error handling class I suppose

Comment: Yes but the error is undefined variable name. I think it comes from your first Loading JS file. Check your code with the name of 'clean' . It's not defined. Also make sure to uninstall the app and rebuild

Comment: @AkilaDevinda Thanks for pointing me in right direction

Comment: Your welcome and glad it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AkilaDevinda suggested I looked for `clean` in code and found that I am using `cleanExtractedImagesCache()` function from library
`react-native-image-filter-kit`.

Issue was that I had disabled auto-link for android in **`react-native.config.js`**

```
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    'react-native-image-filter-kit': {
      platforms: {
        android: null, // disable Android platform, other platforms will still autolink if provided
      },
    },
}
```

Hence, in android `cleanExtractedImagesCache()` wasn't found and caused undefined error. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helps :)